# Emmet overwritten snippet

Tags: html, html-lists, code-snippets, overwrite, emmet

I have been following the lessons on HTML and CSS provided by Jeffery Way on Tuts+:

http://learncss.tutsplus.com/

I got to the video on Zen Coding:

http://learncss.tutsplus.com/lesson/zen-coding/

I tried installing Zen Code to Sublime Text 2 but couldn't get it to work. I looked around on the web and found Emmet, which seemed like the new best thing. So I installed through the Command Pallete>"Package Install">"Emmet". It works great, the only issue is a snippet I used before is overwritten by Emmet.

The Snippet I used:

```
<snippet>
   <content><![CDATA[
<li type="square">${1:Item} ${2:}
]]></content>
   <tabTrigger>li</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

li + Tab would trigger:

```
<li type="square">
```

Is there a way for me to add this to Emmet in Sublime Text 2? Or use Emmet to accomplish this tag? I found this guide to Emmet tabtriggers, but could not find this one:

http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either create your own snippet in Emmet:
http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/
http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/types/

...or disable `li` snippet from being handled by Emmet:
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Emmet.sublime-settings#L55

...or disable Emmet tab trigger and use Ctrl+E:
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings#L14

...or rename your ST snippet to something like `li2`, `lit`, etc.

Comment: Ok I think I'll go with creating my own snippet in Emmet. It sounds like it will override some other snippets. Will it keep the snippet if I ever have to use for example: ul>li>a