# Unknown CSS Tab Completion in Sublime Text

Tags: css, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I've seen "Tuts+. PSD to WordPress – Minimal Portfolio Theme" and the author uses the tab completion "sep" and then presses tab and voila he gets multiple line comment separator for CSS something like:

```
/****************************************************************************/
/* Name Here */
/****************************************************************************/
```

I want to know how can I achieve this in sublime text? Using what package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tab completion you saw was most likely a **[custom snippet](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html)**

Go to Tools > New Snippet and add the following code

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/****************************************************************************/
/* ${1:Name Here} */
/****************************************************************************/
]]></content>

<tabTrigger>sep</tabTrigger>
<scope>source.css</scope>

</snippet>
```

---

The `${1:Name Here}` is a variable that will focus your cursor to that point

The `<tabTrigger>sep</tabTrigger>` is the defined text that will fire the snippet code with <kbd>tab</kbd>

The `<scope>source.css</scope>` indicates that the snippet will fire when your syntax is set to CSS.

Save with the `.sublime-snippet` file extension. Example: `css-sep.sublime-snippet`

Comment: Awesome! That solves the biggest mystery of the day for my :)

Comment: Oh the emmet plugin does not let this snipper to execute instead I get sep: ; when i press the tab key

Comment: No problem, here are a few options for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/16459117/1342440