# Sublime Text 3 - Snippet doesn't fire on tab, only on CSS file

Tags: css, windows-7, sublimetext3, code-snippets

I have a snippet that does not fire on the tab trigger. Here's my code...

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
.contentBox ul{list-style: none; padding: 0;}
.contentBox ul li{padding-left: 2.5em; text-indent: -0.7em; margin-bottom: 4px;}
.contentBox ul li:before{content: "${1:•} "; color: #${2:Bullet color};}
]]></content>
  <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
  <tabTrigger>xcv</tabTrigger>
  <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
  <!-- <scope>source.css</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

If I'm on an HTML file, the tab trigger (xcv) works. However, on a CSS file, it doesn't work. BUT if I select the snippet through CTRL+SHIFT+P, it will output the code. Also on CSS files, if I try the tab trigger within a selector, it will work.

I've tried setting the scope to source.css and text.css (as well as guiding it out), and none make a difference. I've also restarted Sublime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue with you and I had found a resolution to solve it.

I had read it at: [Unknown CSS Tab Completion in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529315/unknown-css-tab-completion-in-sublime-text)

To fixed it:

Your code: `<tabTrigger>sep</tabTrigger>`

Exact code to it work: `<tabTrigger>sep/</tabTrigger>`

Hope it helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for some time, and couldn't find any solution anywhere, and sure it works by putting a / behind the trigger, but what makes it not working in the first place ?

I think the answer here is emmet, and i fixed this by simply writing my trigger and instead of pressing the tab button, i press ctrl+space, and that  somehow works for me, but i don't know why.

Hope this helps someone out there :)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, use the following tags and then restart Sublime.

```
<tabTrigger>css3</tabTrigger><br>
<scope>source.css</scope>
```