# custom snippet is not working in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am creating a custom snippet in sublime text 3 with following code but somehow it's not working when I type my desire `tabTrigger` with pressing the `tab`

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[alter pot water it your pot.]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>alter</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
<scope>source.html</scope>
<!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
<description>My Fancy Snippet</description>
</snippet>
```

after that Im typing `alter` in html document and pressing `tab` but doesn't showing the content. can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the wrong scope, it needs to be `text.html`.

Also make sure, the text scope is enabled for autocompletions (by default it isn't). Go to *Preferences>Settings - User* and add `text` (or `text.html` for HTML only) to `auto_complete_selector`.

Comment: You probably have to enable completions for the text scope, see my edited answer

Comment: You can also enable the autocomplete selector *everywhere* by setting the autocomplete selector config option in Preferences>Settings - User to true: i.e..:    
 "auto_complete_selector": true

Answer (score 4):

[Sublime Text 3 - Snippet doesn't fire on tab, only on CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629441/sublime-text-3-snippet-doesnt-fire-on-tab-only-on-css-file)

in short

change

```
<tabTrigger>alter</tabTrigger>
```

to

```
<tabTrigger>alter/</tabTrigger>
```

Answer (score 4):

The content of your `<scope>` tag is wrong.  To determine the current scope under your cursor, run the following in the Sublime console:

```
view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].begin())
```

To bring up the console on Windows, press Ctrl+'

Answer (score 0):

I would also make sure, in addition to the information above, that the document that you are opening is an HTML document in Sublime text. Look in the bottom right hand corner. When I first started using the custom snippets they didn't work and it was because the default file type in Sublime is plain text. You can click on the bottom right to change the document to the proper file type.

Comment: please follow thus [URL]( http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. I'm using Sublime Text Build 3083 in Win 8.1

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log();]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>JS Console Log</description>
</snippet>
```

You can try it.